# jQuery: How to trigger different actions with the same click function (with different elements)

Tags: jquery, click

I'm trying to change the background-color of a bar through a specific click function. Each element (a dropdown list) clicked changes the color of this same bar. But I don't want 5 click functions and i'm trying other ways, but until now, nothing is working. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

With this code the console says that "targets[i] is not a function..." I know this is kind of elementary but i've searched and searched and nothing seemed to suit me.

```
var targets=['#first-img, #second-img, #third-img, #fourth-img, #fifth-img'];

   for(var i=0; i<targets.length; i++){
       targets[i].click(function(){
           $('#middle-bar').css('color','green');
           $('#middle-bar').css('color','black');
           //and so on...


       })
   }
```

EDIT

well, with this code I get no errors but nothing happens, the color wont change

```
var targets=['#first-img', '#second-img', '#third-img', '#fourth-img', '#fifth-img'];

   for(var i=0; i<targets.length; i++){
       $(targets[i]).click(function(){
           $('#middle-bar').css('color','green');
           $('#middle-bar').css('color','black');
       })
   }
```

EDIT:

This is the HTML:

```
        <div class="col-6 vertical-middle">
            <div class="text-left">
                <span class="font1 uppercase s22 white">Cook With</span>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-6 vertical-middle">
            <div class="text-right">

                <div class="dropdown-images" id="drop-img">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x30" alt="Nestlé">

                    <div class="custom-drop-images">

                        <img id="first-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x30" alt="">
                       <img id="second-img" src=" first-img http://via.placeholder.com/50x30" onClick="" alt="">
                         <img id="third-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x30" alt="">
                        <img id="fourth-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x30" alt="">
                         <img id="fifth-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x30" alt="">

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
```

And the current JS:

```
var targets=['#first-img', '#second-img', '#third-img', '#fourth-img', '#fifth-img'];

for(var i=0; i<targets.length; i++){
    $(targets[i]).click(function(){
        $('#middle-bar').css('color','green');
        $('#middle-bar').css('color','black');
         $('#middle-bar').css('color','brown');
         $('#middle-bar').css('color','blue');
         $('#middle-bar').css('color','red');
    })
}
```

The output is odd, the bar still won't change, but I can see the second image background turning red...

Comment: Is `targets` dynamically populated or hard coded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simpler solution via plain old JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeColor(color) {
        document.getElementById('middle-bar').style.background = color;
    }
</script>
```

And then, the HTML:

```
 <img id="second-img" src=" first-img http://via.placeholder.com/50x30" onClick="changeColor('red');" alt="">
```

Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really looked into your code yet, but the first thing that I see is that your array only has one element.  Your single quotes are wrapping your comma separated values, so you only have one element.

Second, you should try $(targets[i]).on('click', function(e){ // your code here });

targets[i] is not selector.  It is just a string, and not a function.  You cannot attach an event to a string.  You need to wrap that string inside $(targets[i]) to make it a valid selector function.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is hard coded and wont change then you could just do

```
$('#first-img, #second-img, #third-img, #fourth-img, #fifth-img').click(function(){
    //your code here
})
```

if the array is dynamically populated they need to be jQuery selectors, that is why you are getting the `target[i]` is not a function error. for that you could do this

`$(targets[i]).click(function(){...`

also, your array has only one element, the quotes are around the whole thing, not each element

Answer (score 0):

"well, with this code I get no errors but nothing happens, the color wont change"

Make sure that your DOM elements already exist when the code runs.  You can guarantee that your

```
var targets=['#first-img', '#second-img', '#third-img', '#fourth-img', '#fifth-img'];
```

elements exist by wrapping your code inside (document).ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var targets=['#first-img', '#second-img', '#third-img', '#fourth-img', '#fifth-img'];

for(var i=0; i<targets.length; i++){
    $(targets[i]).click(function(){
        $('#middle-bar').css('color','green');
        $('#middle-bar').css('color','black');
    })
}  
});
```

It is also recommended by JQuery that you attach events using .ON, in this manner:

```
$('#elementID').on('click', function(e){   
     // your code here
});
```